# delete rows until certain value is reached

Tags: vba, excel

I need to delete one row at a time and loop it until the activecell = "X"
Why wouldn't something as simple as this work?

```
Sub SubMac4_1Loop()
    Do Until ActiveCell.Value <> "X"
        Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your narrative directly contradicts your code.

Delete rows until the [ActiveCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193314.aspx) equals **X**.

```
Sub SubMac4_1Loop()
    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "X"
        Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    Loop
End Sub
```

Delete rows until the [ActiveCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193314.aspx) does not equal **X**.

```
Sub SubMac4_1Loop()
    Do Until ActiveCell.Value <> "X"
        Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: fwiw, this method of a potentially boundless [Range.Delete method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223863(v=office.11).aspx) is probably not a good idea. It is just too easy to have it accidentally run into a 'forever' loop. It needs error control so it doesn't even enter the loop unless there is a possibility that the loop will end and I would also put an optional parameter into it so that it is not shown to the general user in the Alt+F8 Macros dialog.

Comment: Is using `ActiveCell` and `Selection` okay here? Or should OP try and re-write not needing the active cells?  (Or is that part of what your comment says, just not explicitly?)

Comment: @BruceWayne - I endeavored to answer the original question as posed by the OP but I also wanted to point out that this is at best 'not best practise) and at worse a potential forever loop that will hoop the current Excel instance. If no **X** is found, it will just keep eating up rows until the application crashes or the user intentionally crashes it. Unfortunately, there really isn't enough information to write an alternative; need column to look for X in, etc. Hopefully, this is just testing syntax and principles and the real code will be different.

Answer (score 1):

```
Do Until ActiveCell.Value <> "X"
```

do as long as NOT activecell is NOT X => do while active cell = x

```
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> "X"
```

or

```
 Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "X"
```

will do it

Comment: Will this run correctly or will it just keep looping?Sub SubMac4_1_3_1()
    SubMac3
    SubMac3_1
    SubMac3_2
    SubMac4
    SubMac4_1Loop
    SubMac4_2
End Sub
Sub SubMac4_1_3_1Loop()
    
    Do While ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Value <> ""
        SubMac4_1_3_1
    Loop
    
End Sub

Comment: i dont realy get it... but as far as it looks: if the active cell changes somewhere (and will encounter an empty cell sooner or later, it will stop. if not, it will run till the end of all time and space :D